# How to fatten body parts in blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, faces

I need to thicken ("fatten") some parts of my mesh. I tried to scale X but it deforms and make a mess. How do I solve this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Shrink/Fatten tool in edit mode with proportional editing turned on.

To use Shrink/Fatten press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

To enable proportional editing press <kbd>O</kbd>

Example of this method used on part a sphere:[image]